# Simple slideshow with dynamically added images doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple JQuery slideshow, which works perfectly when the images are added to the HTML. However, I need to add the images with AJAX, which causes the following problem:

The way the slideshow JS works is that it starts by hiding all slideshow images except for the first one. After that, it hides and shows the next image. But because the images are added via AJAX, they don't get hidden at the beginning. They just stack up and disappear one by one. After they all disappear the slideshow starts.

This is the slideshow JS:

```
$("#spotlight_holder > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
    $('#spotlight_holder > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#spotlight_holder');
}, 5000);
```

I know I have to use the on() function to do event delegation, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

EDIT

Here's the HTML of the slideshow:

```
<div id="spotlight_holder">
    <div class="show spotlight_item snap_item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="show spotlight_item snap_item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="show spotlight_item snap_item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="show spotlight_item snap_item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="show spotlight_item snap_item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

When the AJAX is run, this is the structure of the HTML.

My AJAX is:

```
function load_slideshow_images() {
    $.post( "http://localhost/snapll_back/moment/spotlight.php?id="+url_user_id,
    function(info) {        
        $("#spotlight_holder").html(info);
    });
    return false;      
}
```

Comment: Without your code it's difficult to help you. I think you have just to wrapp your code into a function and execute it when the images are in the DOM

Comment: My code is in the question

Comment: I don't see your AJAX call for retrieve your images

Comment: I've added more details to the question.

Comment: Just add you slider code after `$("#spotlight_holder").html(info);`

Comment: @Freez I've already done that. It's completely at the bottom of my JS...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66933/discussion-between-freez-and-user3608176).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to load the images asynchronously, that is okay... once you have retrieved them then initialise your slider.

I am not sure which slider plugin you are using or if you are building one, but assuming you are using [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html) you could do this

```
<div class="pics"> 
  <!-- loading these images ansync instead -->
  <!-- <img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
  <img src="images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> -->
</div> 


$(document).ready(function(){
  loadImages();
  startSlideShow();
});

function loadImages() {
  // load images into pics once retrieved
  $(".pics").append("<img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />")
}

function startSlider() {
  $('#pics').cycle('fade');
}
```

You could have a loader running until the slider is ready and once the images are loaded hide the loader.

Also it could be better to use a binding/MV* framework like knockout.js or Angular, as these allow for you to set up the html in a declarative manner and bind in the values for your images from your models. [Here](http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/) is an example of a simple slider using AngularJs

Comment: I'm not using any plugins, just JQuery.

Comment: I've added more details to my question